# how do I get the DatePicker value date to use in js()

Tags: php, javascript, filter, grid, atk4

I want to control a grid with dates on two DatePickers, 
I'm reloading the whole page, although it may be better to reload the grid only.
Anyway, I can't get the value of the datepicker in order to use it in the array in the reload, how should I do that? I have this:

```
class page_caja extends Page {
function init(){
    parent::init();

    if(!$_GET['fInicial']){
        $fInicial=date('d/m/Y');
    }else{
        $fInicial=$_GET['fInicial'];
    }
    if(!$_GET['fFinal']){
        $fFinal=date('d/m/Y');    
    }else{
        $fFinal=$_GET['fFinal'];
    }
    $f=$this->add('Form');

    $inicial=$f->addField('DatePicker','fInicial','Fecha Incial')->set($fInicial);
    $final=$f->addField('DatePicker','fFinal','Fecha Final')->set($fFinal);

    //Tabla de Pagos Pendientes
    $this->add('H3')->set('Movimientos');
    $g=$this->add('MVCGrid');
    $g->setModel('Caja');                
    $g->removeColumn('programaPago');
    $g->addColumn('date','created_dts','Fecha');
    $g->dq->where("DATE(created_dts)>=",$inicial->get());
    $g->dq->where("DATE(created_dts)<=",$final->get());
    $g->addTotals();


    $inicial->js('change',$this->js()->reload(array('fInicial'=>$inicial->js()->value(),'fFinal'=>$final->js()->value())));
    $final->js('change',$this->js()->reload(array('fInicial'=>$inicial->js()->value(),'fFinal'=>$final->js()->value())));


}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is quite good, I don't see anything wrong with it, although I would write it like this. My method uses filter submit and takes one extra reload, but it works quite smooth and simple to understand:

```
$filter = $page->add('Form');
$grid  = $page->add('Grid')->setModel('Caja');

$filter->addField('date','d1')->js('change',$filter->js()->submit());
$filter->addField('date','d2')->js('change',$filter->js()->submit());

if($filter->isSubmited()){z
    $this->memorize('d1',$filter->get('d1'));
    $this->memorize('d2',$filter->get('d2'));
    $grid->js()->reload()->execute();
}

$d1=$this->recall('d1',null);
if($d1)$grid->dq->where('date(created_dts)>=',$d1);

$d1=$this->recall('d2',null);
if($d2)$grid->dq->where('date(created_dts)<=',$d2);
```

You can also incorporate fields into the reload() but then you should be reading $d1 and $d2 from $_GET variable.

If you can't get value from a field, try simpler ways:

```
$form->addField('test')->js('change')
    ->univ()->log(
         $form->getElement('test')->js()->val()
    );
```

Then watch Inspector's Console for output.

Comment: Thanks, those memorize and recall methods are going to be very useful lfor now on (I was relaying on $_GET...), Thanks again!